# How to set Homepage in WebView from edit text?

Tags: android, webview

i have a webview in which i want to add the functionality of changing the homepage through edit text field. like all the browsers do, but from other activity (i want to have this and all the other settings in another activity). is it possible to do so? Thanks

```
        package com.example.app;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.webkit.CookieManager;
        import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
        import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
        import android.webkit.WebSettings;
        import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
        import android.webkit.WebView;
        import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.CompoundButton;
        import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import android.widget.ToggleButton;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            private WebView webView;
            private EditText urlEditText;
            private ProgressBar progress;

            private ToggleButton getToggleButton(int id) {
                return (ToggleButton) findViewById(id);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                getToggleButton(R.id.leave_toggle).setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                        new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton,
                                    boolean isChecked) {
                                if (isChecked) {
                                    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(
                                            false);// Enable Image
                                    // Loading
                                } else {
                                    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(
                                            true);// Enable Image
                                    // Loading
                                }
                            }
                        });

                urlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
                webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());
                webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {// Download Manager
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                            long contentLength) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);// Enable Cookies
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);// Enable Java Script
                webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/"); // Set
                                                            // Home
                                                            // page
                webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);// Remove
                                                                            // ScrollBars
                webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(12);// Set Font Size

                webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);// Enable Flash
                webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);// Transparent Screen When
                                                        // Loading
                webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);// Set Zoom
                // Controls
                webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);// Enable WebView Interaction

                webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8);// Set Cache
                                                                            // (8mb)
                String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()
                        .getAbsolutePath();// Set Cache (8mb)
                webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);// Set Cache (8mb)
                webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);// Set Cache (8mb)
                webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);// Set Cache (8mb)
                webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);// Set
                                                                                // Cache
                                                                                // (8mb)

                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {// Open URL on Error
                    @Override
                    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                            String description, String failingUrl) {// Open URL on Error
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Error.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                // ////8888888888888888**URL BAR AND PROGRESS
                // BAR**888888888888888888888888888888888

                progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progress.setMax(100);

                Button openUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
                openUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String url = urlEditText.getText().toString();

                        if (url.endsWith(".ac") || url.endsWith(".ac.uk")

                            if (!url.startsWith("http://")
                                    && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
                                url = "http://" + url;
                            }
                        }
                        if (validateUrl(url)) {
                            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                            webView.loadUrl(url);

                            MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(10);
                        }
                    }

                    private boolean validateUrl(String url) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }

            private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                    MainActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
                    super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            public void setValue(int progress) {
                this.progress.setProgress(progress);
            }

            // ////8888888888888888**URL BAR AND PROGRESS
            // BAR**888888888888888888888888888888888

            class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url) {

                    webview.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            public void forward(View view) { // Forward Button
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Forward", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                webView.goForward();
            }

            public void back(View view) { // Back Button
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                webView.goBack();
            }

            public void stop(View view) { // Stop Button
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                webView.stopLoading();
            }

            public void reload(View view) { // Reload Button
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Reloading..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                webView.reload();
            }

            // Tools navigation
            public void database(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Edt_Txt.class);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Memory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            public void mini(View view) {
                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Minimized", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                startActivity(startMain);
            }



            public void json(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, JSON.class);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Loading JSON (BETA)",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setTitle("Exit")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        finish();
                                        System.exit(0);
                                    }
                                }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: ues textwatcher in android

Comment: @DIVA i have no idea what is it as i am new to android please assist me if you can

Comment: you wanna change webview url on text change in editext right?

Comment: ?  i want to have a edit text field in some other activity in along with a set as homepage button and when i write a url in that field and press that button, it should set that url as homepage in my webview

Comment: ok so whenever ur webview restart it should show url u setted as home url right?

Comment: yes, it should save that url as default homepage

Comment: did u tried to store url in shared pref on click of ur set home page button? and everytime let webview take url from shared pref

Answer (score 0):

This is code below when u click to set default url as home page :

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putString("URL","http"//sample.com");
  editor.apply();
```

When u set url to browser do this :

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  String url= preferences.getString("URL","");
  if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
  {
    //set url in broswer u will always get as last setted home page url
  }
```

Comment: do you have something for tabs? i am trying to use buttons and give them visibility and have 4 webviews (for 4 tabs) but i need to keep the layout which contains those buttons common for all the activities

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502274/calling-upload-manager-in-webview-android